# How can I associate a button with a form using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working with Angular 6.x, and I'd like to associate a submit button located outside the form in the DOm with it. That is, I want to accomplish something structurally equivalent to this:

```
<button type='submit' form='myform'>
  click me!
</button>

<form id='myform' action='#' onsubmit='console.log("wheee")'>
  <input type='submit' value='me too'/>
</form>
```

I.e. I want to handle the `submit` event from the form element.

Is there a way to do this without going through `nativeElement` or without moving/duplicating the submit handler on the click event of the button?

Answer (score 1):

> You can achieve by reference `#form` of form and passing the same reference to button.

```
<button type='button' (click)="form.onsubmit()">
  click me!
</button>

<form id='myform' #form action='#' onsubmit='console.log("wheee")'>
  <input type='submit' value='me too'/>
</form>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnneks

Answer (score 1):

Tyr it like this.

```
<button type='submit'  (click)="myForm.submit()">
  click me!
</button>

<form id='myform' action='#' #myForm onsubmit='console.log("wheee")'>
  <input type='submit' value='me too'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a Reactive Form and then on the click of this button. call a function that would extract the value of the form and do something on it.

This way, you can also do things like disabling the button if the form is invalid.

So here's what your form will look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [, Validators.required],
      lastName: [, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log('Form Submitted with value: ', this.userForm.value);
  }
}
```

And here's the template:

```
<h3>User Form</h3>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<button (click)="submitForm()" [disabled]="userForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-submit-button-outside-the-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.